# Omitting a dinkus / separator if it would be the first or last element on the page

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals, ifthenelse

I am working on a book of demotivational aphorisms. Since the aphorisms are brief I'm wrapping them in `samepage` and I allow more than one per page, if they fit.

This kind of layout benefits from some kind of separator / ornament between items.

However, the separator can be omitted if it would be the first or last element on this page. Leaving all the separators as is looks inconsistent - some pages would start with a separator and some not, some pages would end with a separator and some not.

- If the separator would be the first element on this page I'd like to omit it and just continue with the next item.
- If the next item is too large to fit on the page after the separator I'd like to omit the separator and replace it with `\newpage`. (Just omitting the separator wouldn't work since without the separator the next item might fit.)

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[layoutheight = 105 mm, layoutwidth = 74 mm, paperheight = 105 mm, paperwidth = 74 mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pifont}

\hbadness = 10000

\newcommand\Separator{

  \vspace{1em}

  \begin{center}

    \ding{91} \ding{91} \ding{91}

  \end{center}

  \vspace{1em}}

\sloppy

\begin{document}

  \begin{samepage}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \end{samepage}

  \Separator

  \begin{samepage}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  \end{samepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `\Separator` disappear at the top and bottom of pages by dressing it up as `\cleaders`, which behave like glue, but (to quote chapter 21 of The TeXbook)

> [don't] fill space with nothing, [they] fill space with any desired thing.

```tex
\newbox\sepbox 
\newcommand\Separator{
  \setbox\sepbox=\vbox{
    \vspace{1em}
    \begin{center}
      \ding{91} \ding{91} \ding{91}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{1em}
  }
  \cleaders\copy\sepbox\vskip\ht\sepbox}
```

The amount of `\vskip` equals the height of the `\vbox`, therefore the `\cleaders` (if they remain on the page) display exactly one instance of the `\vbox`.

TeX always suppresses glue (or cleaders) that would appear at the top of a page. And pages will never be broken between a `\Separator` and the following aphorism, because TeX sees no legal break point between glue (or cleaders) and a line of text. The break therefore happens *before* the `\Separator`, but the document class or packages that you use insert additional `\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil` at the bottom (which I observed by tracing). Therefore the pages get a ragged bottom.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining a bit why the \vbox is necessary, what is to3em and what is \vss? I tried googling but don't understand very well why and how this solution works.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you replaced 1 em with 3 em but, if anything, the empty space looks a bit smaller?

Comment: I have edited my answer to keep more of your code.